# How to listen for "change" event while also binding to a property?

Tags: javascript, ember.js

I can't find out a way to both listen to the change event AND bind to a property in my controller at the same time! I can do one or another, but not both at the same time;

The code I have;

```
//I am able to get change event this way - works good
<input type="email" {{action "checkEmailAvailability" this on="change"}} class="form-control" placeholder="Email"/>

//I can bind to a property this way - works good
{{input type="email" value=email class="form-control" placeholder="Email"}}
```

I cant find a way to both trigger `checkEmailAvailability` action and trigger `change` event at the same time; I have tried googling and some trial/error attempts; including the following (which doesn't works but seems to make sense);

```
//1 Attempt
{{input type="email" change="checkEmailAvailability" value=email class="form-control" placeholder="Email"}}

//2 Attempt
<input type="email" {{action= "checkEmailAvailability" this on="change"}} {{bind-attr value=email}} class="form-control" placeholder="Email"/>
```

I must be able to listen to change event so I can make an ajax call to check wether this email address is available for registering and must listen (with observers) to email property change so I can validate email and emailConfirmation field in "real time".

Answer (score 0):

If you need to fire your action with non built-in input events, you could extend the TextField component and fire your action:

```
App.PersonEmailComponent = Ember.TextField.extend({

 'change-action': null,

  change: function(evt) {

    this.sendAction('change-action', evt);

  } 
});


 {{person-email change-action='validateEmail'}}
```

By default, the input helper responds to some specific view event (keyPress, focusOut, focusIn, insertNewLine, Enter) firing its specific action when those are defined.

```
{{input type="email" key-press="checkEmailAvailability" }}
```

http://emberjs.jsbin.com/jisij/2/edit

Comment: I want to receive a notification for the change event since I don't want to send lots of requests to the server (one for each key press event) to check whether the email supplied is available. Do you have any idea of how can I achieve this?

Comment: Thanks, gonna give your code a try then I tell you if I can get it to work!

Answer (score 0):

Bind the value, then make a function that observes it:

```
App.MyController = Ember.ObjectController.extend({
  email: null,

  checkEmailAvailability: function({
    var email = this.get('email')
    console.log("Email changed to: " + email);
  }).observes('email')
});
```

Comment: Hey @aceofspades, this is exatcly my code, the problem is knowing when the user stopped editing the input (the html "change" event)

Comment: So you're doing an autocomplete thing? I would do this with a JS timer that gets reset every time the email changes, and fires after the delay.

Comment: This would be an ugly workaround in my humble opinion